# Twitter API query that filters out retweets and replies

Tags: r, twitter

I am using R to do datamining on tweets. I currently use a search query that is keyword.

```
keyword = "eurovision -filter:replies"
tweets = searchTwitter(keyword,n = 200,lang = 'en')
```

I also want to filter out retweets but the following keyword does not filter replies nor retweets:

```
keyword = "eurovision -filter:replies -filter:retweets"
```

I searched the web and the documentation of the twitter API
(https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/standard-operators ) 
but could not find a working example. there has to be an easy solution right?

Comment: The `rtweet` package might help you. It's easy to use and well documented. https://rud.is/books/21-recipes/searching-for-tweets.html

Comment: It was not really what i was looking for, but the examples gave me an idea. I solved the issue using:

    keyword = "eurovision -RT -filter:retweets"